# Does ri know about all ruby classes?

Tags: ruby, ri

When I pass `CSV` to `ri` I get this output

> Nothing known about CSV

I thought all ruby classes are documented with ri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is a part of standard library and is fully documented. That issue may be linked wit rvm using. Try to prepare `rvm docs generate` command.

Answer (score 1):

If RI returns "NOTHING KNOWN ABOUT..." the documentation may be missing.

RI documentation isn't included when Ruby is installed.
It must be manually generated - ideally, immediately after installing EACH VERSION of Ruby (before the downloaded installation files are cleaned up).

To generate it:

```
$ rvm docs generate
```

If that doesn't work, check this [RVM.io page](https://rvm.io/rubies/docs) for command options & scenarios.